# How can I change a bullet shooting speed and keep the bullet shooting distance using physics?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootBullets : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bulletDistance;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float fireRate;
    public Rigidbody bullet;

    private float gunheat;
    private bool shoot = false;
    private GameObject bulletsParent;
    private GameObject[] startpos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bulletsParent = GameObject.Find("Bullets");
        startpos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Pod_Weapon");
    }

    void Fire()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < startpos.Length; i++)
        {
            Rigidbody bulletClone = (Rigidbody)Instantiate(bullet, startpos[i].transform.position, startpos[i].transform.rotation, bulletsParent.transform);

            bulletClone.velocity = transform.forward * bulletDistance;
            // The bullet or any ammo/weapon should be on Y rotation = 0
            Destroy(bulletClone.gameObject, 0.5f);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (automaticFire == false)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Fire();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (shoot == true)
            {
                    Fire();

                    shoot = false;
            }
        }

        if (gunheat > 0) gunheat -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (gunheat <= 0)
        {
            shoot = true;
            gunheat = fireRate;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to keep the distance like in this line :

```
bulletClone.velocity = transform.forward * bulletDistance;
```

but also to control the bullet speed. maybe it's a problem when using physics ?
my problem is that the bullets shot too fast.

the question is if it's possible to control the speed and keep the distance using physics ?
and does the function Fire should be called from Update or FixedUpdate ?

Comment: I would try to write a more describing title. I think the problem is a math or a calculation's one.

Comment: Please be more specific. Possibilities are endless. Do you want to control the speed over lifetime or do you want to limit the bullet speed to a maximum value. You could also just divide the speed by a value.

Comment: @flyingchris over lifetime. I want to keep the distance for example 50 and I want to be able to control the speed over the distance. so the distance is 50 and the speed can be 10 or 20 or 30 all the way.

Comment: `distance = velocity  * time `
so `velocity = distance / time` you can calculat velocity before you set it.
for example v = 50 / 10s , v = 5

Comment: Does your bullet have gravity? or just forward move.

Comment: @TimChang It does. The bullet have a Rigidbody attached and use gravity is true,

Comment: Would you consider writing your own physics? Becase you can chage 'time delta' value. it's eazy to make slow or fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant something different with "over lifetime" but it doesn't matter. The speed is currently only set once so it is only dependent on the distance you shot the bullet from. Not the distance left to the target.

If you want to keep distance in the equation but decrease the result, have you thought about dividing the speed? IE add something like this

```
bulletClone.velocity = transform.forward * bulletDistance / 3;
```

you can also compare the speed to a maximum value and decide on which to pick IE

```
if(bulletDistance < 30)
{
bulletClone.velocity = transform.forward * bulletDistance;
}
else
{
bulletClone.velocity = transform.forward * 30
}
```

You can set the speed to anything you want.